# Prove: $R \circ R \subseteq R \implies R$ is transitive for $R \circ R = \emptyset$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have managed to prove that if $R \circ R \subseteq R \implies R$ is transitive for the general case. I am trying to do it for $R=\emptyset$.

To show that R is transitive we need: $\forall x,y,z \in A ((x,y)\in R \land (y,z) \in R \implies (x,z) \in R)$.

Would the following reasoning work or is it missing something?

If $R\circ R = \emptyset$ then $\forall (x,z)\in R(\forall y \in A((x,y)\notin R \lor (y,z)\notin R))$. Now if $R=\emptyset$ then it is transitive. Otherwise let $(x,z) \in R.$ Now let $y \in A$. Thus we have $(x,y) \notin R \lor (y,z) \notin R$ and $x,y,z \in A$.

1. **Case 1**: $(x,y) \notin R$ therefore $R$ is transitive.
2. **Case 2**: $(y,z) \notin R$ therefore $R$ is transitive.

Since the cases are exhaustive and $x,y,z$ are arbitrary elements of $A$ the proof is done. (I am not sure about this part since I stated that $(x,z)\in R$ and thus are not really arbitrary elements of $A$.

Comment: since $\varnothing$ is a transitive relation there is nothing to prove.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't use the hypothesis $R\ne\emptyset$ in the proof you have.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: Sorry that was a typo, it should have been "trying to do it for $R\circ R = \emptyset$".

Comment: @egreg: You are right, I don't :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove that a relation $R$ on the set $A$ is transitive when $R\circ R\subseteq R$.

Let $x,y,z\in A$ and assume $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$. By definition of $R\circ R$, we have $(x,z)\in R$. Therefore $R$ is transitive.

> *Are we using somewhere that $R\circ R\ne\emptyset$ or $R\ne\emptyset$?*

No.